# font from google fonts is not working with media query

Tags: html, css, web

So, I want to add a custom font to my web page. I grabbed the font from the google fonts via @media query and specified it in font-family. But it is not working. What's the issue?
Code provided below, thanks.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Chakra+Petch&display=swap')

body{
    font-family: 'Chakra Petch', sans-serif;
}
```

I've tried to comment-out @media part of the code and css worked after that. So, my issue now is with importing font imo.

And of course, I've tried downloading font and link it in my HTML as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/ChakraPetch-Regular.ttf">
```

Comment: "comment-out `@media` part of the code" — What `@media` part of the code?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/ChakraPetch-Regular.ttf">` — fonts are not stylesheets.

Comment: I think this is a typo problem where you forgot the `;` between the import statement and the body selector.

Comment: I believe @Quentin is correct here. It's the case of a missing `;` I can add a snippet but I don't want to take away from Quentin's answer :)

Comment: @heyitsjhu — We don't answer questions about typos here; there aren't useful for other visitors. That's why "Typo" is on the list of close vote reasons.